# Why do mobs have my gear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I searched the wiki but there doesn't seem to be any mention of my particular topic. I somewhat un-commonly find zombies and skeletons with my EXACT gearset equipped. They have the same armor, and weapon that I do. I have confirmed this many times as I find mobs with jetpacks equipped, swords with knockback, and mismatched armor exactly the same as mine.

I havent died, these mobs are SPAWNING with my gear equipped.

[image]

I'm currently running a hybrid pack of both Unhinged and Unleashed.

I have every mod in Unhinged installed and these mods as well from Unleashed:

- Adv Power Management
- Adv Solar Panels
- Biblio Craft Mods (all three)
- Binnies Mods
- Computer Craft
- Damage Indicators
- Equivalent Exchange 3
- Extra Utilities
- GraviSuite
- Magic Bees
- Misc Periphreals
- ObsidiPlates
- Plugins for Forestry
- Soul Shards
- ThaumCraft

I also installed:

- Logistics Pipes
- Infernal Mobs
- Adv Machines

Comment: While you're still wearing it? Maybe they shop at the same places.

Comment: Zombies definitely spawn in wearing/wielding mod-added gear, but the *exact* matching set as you is weird.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I haven't seen this in game. Is there a source?

Comment: @Coronus Personal experience? \*shrug\* I'm running a modpack that I built myself that includes various new gear, and the mobs occasionally spawn with bits of it.

Comment: If they have your gear... don't you feel... naked?

Comment: You mention jetpacks, so I assume this isn't vanilla. What mods are you running?

Comment: @gnovice FTB, in the tags.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie There are many FTB versions.

Comment: @gnovice I wonder if we should start using more specific tags like [minecraft-ftb-ultimate] and [minecraft-ftb-unhinged]…

Comment: I have seen this on two occasions in FTB Unleashed.  One time, I killed the mob (a zombie pigman dressed identically as me) with a bow and he dropped the helmet I was wearing with the EXACT SAME remaining power.  The other time the zombie did not drop anything.

Comment: I'm seeing Etho reproduce this in his recent video. Maybe it's part of the design of IC2? I'm not sure exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How often do you die? [Zombies have the ability to pick up and equip items](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Armed_Zombie) that are on the ground. If you die near them, then return for your stuff, they may be poised to use it against you.

If you're not dying often, then one of the mods must be adding this feature in. I know [skeletons and zombies have been seen with high-end equipment like nanosuits](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/equipment-on-skeletons-zombies.1881/), which [appears to have been a Halloween prank](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&postID=83665) included in the IndustrialCraft<sup>2</sup> mod. The IC2 config file would probably be the first place I would look for an answer.

Comment: no, this isnt gear they picked up. They SPAWN with my gear.

Answer (score -5):

In my version of Minecraft (using mod Shape Shifter Z), mobs pick up my equipment and use it against me. I think yours is somewhat like that but they spawn with your equipment, or it's a graphical error with the mod. Another possibility is that you dropped that equipment and they equipped it or you died previously and they took your stuff.

Comment: This comment (1) is very poor grammatically, and (2) isn't a proper answer and doesn't really help the person who asked the question. Please consider editing your answer to fix these problems, or removing the answer if needed.

Comment: i have fixed that mistake with my awnser sorry. >:^|

Comment: What you're describing is vanilla Minecraft behaviour. What the question is describing isn't.